# how to develop a magento website from scratch . how to integrate a html pages with magento functionality

Tags: php, html, magento

I want to develop a Magento website from scratch means i am having a HTML developed pages and i want to integrate these pages with magento functionality . I don't know how to  start as i am searching it continously and not getting any suitable stuff. I want to know all the suitable steps in order to integrate my custom HTML pages with Magento functionality.Any help would be appreciated.
I already know how to install custom theme in magento website and i don't want to create a custom theme in magento all i want is to integrate custom html pages with magento functionality

Comment: You need to learn PHP, to call the methods within Magento that output what you need.

Comment: I already know PHP i just want to know the steps i need to integrate custom html pages with magento functioning

Comment: Best way would be to create a custom theme, I don't know why you don't want to. Otherwise maybe you should use something else than Magento.